# Building pip package for multiple platforms

Tags: python, pip, swig, pypi, distutils

I have a project written in C++ with a binding for Python created with Swig. The use of the Python binding depends off of a shared library.

Using distutils I have successfully created a pip package for x86_64 linux (my host machine). Here is a stripped down version of my `setup.py` file

```py
setuptools.setup(
    name='example',
    distclass=BinaryDistribution,
    version='0.0.1',
    author='moi',
    description='example Python API',
    keywords='example, pypi, package',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    #packages=[''],
    package_dir={'': 'Python'},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where='Python')
)
```

This generates a wheel named `example-0.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`.

What is the proper way to generate wheels for different platforms, for example allowing a package to be used for OSX as well as Linux based systems while only being in possession of one of the target machines.

I think the manylinux1_x86_64 tag is a big generalization, does this mean all linux based systems of x86_64 architecture can utilize this package? Ubuntu, Kali, Fedora?

Comment: "*What is the proper way to generate wheels for different platforms…?*" Build on that platforms. Using real hardware, virtual machines or containers (for running containers with different architectures container managers use hidden virtual machines anyway). Example: https://pypi.org/project/CT3/#files a lot of wheels for all Python versions on different architectures; built at Github Actions on [all possible OSes](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/blob/402d473752147811a455a64ac854f2e686d4287c/.github/workflows/test-publish.yaml#L15).

Comment: "*I think the manylinux1_x86_64 tag is a big generalization, does this mean all linux based systems of x86_64 architecture can utilize this package? Ubuntu, Kali, Fedora?*" Yes. At least they should.